# Microsoft Office Headings and sub headings

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013

I have  a MS Word 2013 document that goes.

1. Intro
2. Methods

   2.1 Method A

   2.2 Method B

   2.3 Method C
3. Results

Now everything is working with the MS Word Headings and subheadings. But the last paragraph of the Methods (after Method C --2.3--) belongs to the main methods heading (2) and not the sub-heading 2.3.

How can I can this paragraph out of subheading 2.3 and into heading 2 although in comes after 2.3?

I want the paragraph that begins, "While all three type" to belong to Heading 2 not 2.3.

[image: sample]

Comment: Try backspacing before the problem paragraph and creating a new line instead using SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: no luck it still belongs to 2.3